# Getting blog posts to filter by category after changing my default view

Tags: view, blog, settings

I am using Sharepoint 2013 for work and I am self taught so far. I have a blog page setup that I have a list of categories that I was using to sort all the posts by. I had changed my view setting for the category pages and now instead of having all my posts sorted into each folder based on category selection, I am seeing all the posts in every category.

How can I fix this to where each category folder only sees posts that have that category selected?

Answer (score 0):

Create a post webpart in a page and provide category as a query string in that page URL i.e. /posts.aspx?category=category1. Save the page.

Open the page in SharePoint Designer and edit the file in advanced mode. Search for `<ParameterBindings>` tag.

Under this tag, bind category parameter like below:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Category" Location="QueryString(category)" />
```

In name attribute, the column name comes onto which filtration of view is carried out.

On the page, which contains the folder structure based on category of a post, provide link for categories on respective folder.

1. Folder 1 --> /posts.aspx?category=category1
2. Folder 2 --> /posts.aspx?category=category2
3. Folder 3 --> /posts.aspx?category=category3